# what does 0,1,2 value indicate in eslintrc file?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
"react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
```

In my .eslintrc file under rules object, I've this property and other properties with value, 0, 1 and 2. What does the value 0, 1, 2 indicate?

Comment: There are levels of errors: 0 — turn off. 1 — warning, 2 — error

Comment: @Nik can you add this as an answer? If you have links to documentation that talks about this, even better.

Comment: @zedfoxus I added this as an answer with links to the documentation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are levels of rules:

> "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
>
> "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
>
> "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when
>   triggered)

For example:

- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 0` — won't show the error, if you use setState in componentDidMount
- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 1` — will show the warning
- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 2` — will show the error.

So these values are similar to:

- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: "off"` == `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 0`
- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: "warning"` == `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 1`
- `react/no-did-mount-set-state: "error"` === `react/no-did-mount-set-state: 2`

Also, you can check it in the documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules